# JavaScript how to get element by xpath from HTML text

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am trying to get elements from the different pages by XPath.

So I managed to get HTML as text and used `DOMParser.parseFromString()` to make it `HTMLDocument`
then I tried to use `document.evaluate()` but it doesn't return any elements.
Here is the code

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, "text/html");

    const headings = xmlDoc.evaluate(xpath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

    console.log(headings)

    let Heading = headings.iterateNext();

    console.log(Heading)

    let items = []

    while (Heading) {
      items.push(Heading.textContent);
      Heading = headings.iterateNext();
      console.log(items)
    }

  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "url within the same domain", true);
xhttp.send();
```

and that's the output from console.log (headings):

```
XPathResult { resultType: 4, invalidIteratorState: false }
​invalidIteratorState: false
resultType: 4*
```

And the eading is `null`

example that i run in console on 'https://www.aliexpress.com'
expected result is: '1. Contact Seller'

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText)
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, "text/html");

    const headings = xmlDoc.evaluate('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/span[1]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

    console.log(headings)

    let Heading = headings.iterateNext();

    console.log(Heading)

    let items = []

    while (Heading) {
      items.push(Heading.textContent);
      Heading = headings.iterateNext();
      console.log(items)
    }

  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.aliexpress.com/p/buyerprotection/index.html", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I could probably make some function that changes the XPath expression to a regular expression and find the element in the HTML string but I think there is a better way

​

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of `xhttp.responseText`, your xpath expression, and your expected output given your sample html?

Comment: @JackFleeting actually i was trying to do it on alliexpres.  I think the xhhtp.responseText is proper because i looked and it looks like html code from given url. But then i tried to do this on some small website and this code worked

Comment: With JavaScript, here on StackOverflow you can embed executable snippets of HTML/JavaScript/CSS to demonstrate your issue. So don't make us guess what's wrong (namespaces?), just show the relevant code as an executable snippet so we see exactly which HTML you have, which XPath and which JavaScript and how it fails.

Comment: I notice in the non-working code, `xpath` doesn't seem to be defined:
`const headings = xmlDoc.evaluate(xpath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);`

Answer (score 1):

That page you are using XPath against is probably built dynamically by loading/filling parts with JavaScript so while your XPath `/html/body/div[3]` finds a `div` elements with children when used inside the browser console on a window that has the page loaded the attempt against the raw/pure HTML result loaded with a HTTP GET request finds an empty `div` element. That way the selection deeper down the tree with e.g. `/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/span[1]` finds no elements at all.

Thus if you expect to use XPath against some fully loaded/Javascript enhanced HTML document you might need Puppeteer https://pptr.dev/ or similar.

Comment: The code he's pasting into the console is pulling the HTML file as text, same as the non-working example.

Comment: @MichaelG, I am not sure what you are trying to explain with your comment but my point with the answer is that the used XPath `/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/span[1]` selects the right element with e.g. `$x('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/span[1]')` in the browser console if the used URL is loaded in the browser window but if you load the raw/pure HTML text the selection fails as `/html/body/div[3]` finds a `div` element but that is an empty element so any attempt like `/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/section/span[1]` to select nodes inside of the `div` fails finding anything.